# aframe - How to Import Google cardboard created images

Tags: aframe

How do I use a Cardboard Camera 360 image in `aframe`?

The resolution of Cardboard Camera is not `2:1`. Can this be corrected with an `img` tag parameter?

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** I have created a web app for viewing Cardboard Camera images. You still need to [convert](https://storage.googleapis.com/cardboard-camera-converter/index.html), but after that it's as easy as [dragging and dropping onto this page](https://spano.pyrik.dev/).

It is also possible to upload to Imgur and share via URL using this kind of url:

https://spano.pyrik.dev/?url=https://i.imgur.com/PgAHSy8.jpg

For more details see [this page](https://github.com/bryik/stereo-panorama-viewer/).

---

Right now it is not easy to display Cardboard Camera images in A-Frame with proper stereo. But if you're really keen:

1. Get vr.jpg source files off your phone and onto your computer.
2. Use [this web service](https://storage.googleapis.com/cardboard-camera-converter/index.html) to convert the vr.jpg to over-under equirectangular.
3. Split the image obtained in step (2) using a tool like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). This command works:

   magick convert <IMAGE.png> -crop 1x2@ +repage +adjoin pano_%d.png

Rename the outputs "left" and "right".

4. Create an A-Frame scene with two  entities textured with the left and right images. Use the [stereo component](https://github.com/oscarmarinmiro/aframe-stereo-component) to show the left-textured sky to the left eye and the right-textured sky to the right eye. **Or download/fork [this repository](https://github.com/bryik/aframe-cardboard-camera).**

Here's [an example](https://bryik.github.io/aframe-cardboard-camera/examples/mountain.html) using a sample from the Cardboard Camera app.

Answer (score 2):

First you can preview the image via any photo app, then use `share` function to save the image to your email or other place you can get the image. The 360 image's file name created by cardboard camera will be `IMG_yyyymmdd-xxxxxx.vr.jpg`.

For 360 image, you could try render it onto a `a-curvedimage`. a-curvedimage will render the image onto a cylinder.

The default settings for a-curvedimage is not used for cardboard camera  360 image. To get result as render on default `a-sky`, I use following parameters

`<a-curvedimage src="IMG_20160506_123456.vr.jpg"
                height="140" radius="100" theta-length="360"
                rotation="0 0 0"></a-curvedimage>`

You can check [a-curvedimage document](https://aframe.io/docs/primitives/a-curvedimage.html) for more detail.